# Ajax response sometimes empty. Google Chrome response tab shows result correctly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to return response from ajax and push them into global scope so I am use them inside my website anywhere I like.

```
    var getOrderStatus = getOrderStatus(),
        getUserData = getUserData(),
        orderFormReady = $.when(getOrderStatus, getUserData),
        user = {},
        order = {
                pages: {}
        };

    orderFormReady.done(function() {
            console.log("USER");
            console.log(user);
            changePage(parseInt(user.status), "initial");
    });

    getOrderStatus.done(function(data) {
            console.log("Current page: " + data);
    });

    getUserData.done(function(data) {
            var customer = JSON.parse(data);
            user = customer;
    });
```

getOrderStatus() returns int and getUserData returns customer data as json.

Most of the time "user" is empty, but sometimes randomly it displays the data correctly. 90% of the time it is empty. Same goes with orderStatus.

Network tab shows response always. So what I am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can guarantee that getUserData.done() will be executed before orderFormReady.done().

But no matter, just get rid of that and do everything in the .done() of the $.when - the responses from the two requests will be passed into the callback in the same order you passed the Deferreds into the "when" function:

```
var getOrderStatus = getOrderStatus(),
getUserData = getUserData(),
orderFormReady = $.when(getOrderStatus, getUserData),
user = {},
order = {
    pages: {}
};

orderFormReady.done(function(userDataResponse, orderStatusResponse) {
    user = JSON.parse(userDataRespone);
    console.log("User status: " + user.status);
    console.log("Current page: " + orderStatusResponse);
    changePage(parseInt(user.status), "initial");
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ for more info.